# is that possible to access grand parent relation method using delegate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Proposition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :milestone, optional: true
  delegate :title, to: :milestone, allow_nil: true, prefix: :milestone
  delegate :title, to: :milestone, allow_nil: true, prefix: :procedure
end

class Milestone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :procedure
  delegate   :title, to: :procedure, allow_nil: true, prefix: :procedure
end

class Procedure < ApplicationRecord
end


proposition.milestone_title #=> works
proposition.procedure_title #=> error
```

therefor it seems like I need to define method, on Milestone class.
is there any better way to get grandparent methods?

Comment: what the error is raised? `proposition.procedure_title` can you add logs?

Comment: you're treating prefix option incorrectly. Look at examples here https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Answer (score 0):

`delegate` passes a method through from another object, passed via the instance method that exposes it on instances of the current object. So, with:

```
class Proposition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :milestone, optional: true
end

class Milestone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :procedure
  delegate   :title, to: :procedure, allow_nil: true, prefix: :procedure
end
```

For an instance of `Proposition` the method that returns the associated `Milestone` instance is `milestone` as defined by `belongs_to`.

The method on the associated milestone, that returns the title from its associated `Milestone` is `procedure_title` - because `procedure` is defined as the prefix on the delegation in `Milestone`.

So to delegate the `milestone.procedure_title` within `Proposition` the delegate method needs to be:

```
delegate :procedure_title, to: :milestone, allow_nil: true
```

If `Milestone` has its own`title` method, and `Proposition` also has a title, the following would work:

```
class Proposition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :milestone, optional: true
  delegate :title, to: :milestone, allow_nil: true, prefix: :milestone
  delegate :procedure_title, to: :milestone, allow_nil: true
end

class Milestone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :procedure
  delegate   :title, to: :procedure, allow_nil: true, prefix: :procedure
end

class Procedure < ApplicationRecord
end

proposition.title #=> Proposition's title
proposition.milestone_title #=> Milestone's title
proposition.procedure_title #=> Procedure's title
```